# Creating a non-zero-degree sequence by picking from given sequences

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

This question is about cyclic sequences of the digits 1, 2 and 3. We can consider each digit as one vertex of a triangle. Then, each sequence is like a path from 1 to 1 on the triangle. For example, the sequence "12312" is a path that starts at node 1, makes a full trip around the triangle through 2 and 3 back to 1, then goes to 2 and back to 1.

Define the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) of a sequence as the net number of times it surrounds the triangle in the direction 1-2-3. For example, the degree of "12312" is $+1$, the degree of "3213213" is $-2$, and the degree of "1231321" is $0$.

A sequence is called "good" if its degree is non-zero.

Now for the question.

There are three good sequences of the same length. We have to create a new good sequence by picking, for each position, a digit from one of the three sequences. We are not allowed to pick two consecutive digits from the same sequence. Is it always possible to create a new good sequence in this way?

For example, suppose the three good sequences are:

- A: 123111  [degree +1]
- B: 111321  [degree -1]
- C: 321111  [degree -1]

Then we can construct a good sequence by picking in the order:

- ACACAC

which gives the good sequence:

- 123111  [degree +1]

Is this always possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  Consider

- A: 123111111
- B: 111123111
- C: 111111123

No matter how you pick digits, every non-1 digit in the resulting sequence is preceded and succeeded by the digit 1, so the degree would be zero.